# permutations of two lists in python without combining or merging the lists using itertools in python possible?

Tags: python, list, permutation, python-itertools

In the case of two sublists

```
`[[A,B],[1,2]]`
```

I would like to have the output

`[[A,B],[1,2]
    [A,B],[2,1]
    [B,A],[1,2]
    [B,A],[2,1]]`

In the case of three sublists

```
`[[A,B],[1,2], [c, d]]`
```

I would like to have the output

```
`[[A,B],[1,2], [c, d],
 [A,B],[1,2], [d, c],
 [A,B],[2,1], [c, d],
 [A,B],[2,1], [d, c],
 [B,A],[1,2], [c, d],
 [B,A],[1,2], [d, c],
 [B,A],[2,1], [c, d]
 [B,A],[2,1], [d, c]]`
```

Comment: Why don't you want to user itertools?

Answer (score 1):

Using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is the *right way* of doing this (it's part of the standard library so why not?). For example:

```py
from itertools import permutations, product

values = [['A', 'B'], [1, 2]]
sub_permutations = ([list(p) for p in permutations(l)] for l in values)
values_perms = [list(v) for v in product(*sub_permutations)]
```

However, it is of course possible to [implement a permutation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104436/1720199) and [a product function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
def permutations(values):
    if not values: 
        return
    for i in range(len(values)):
        for p in all_perms(values[1:]):
            yield [*p[:i], values[0], *p[i:]]

def product(lists):
    result = [[]]
    for pool in lists:
        result = [r + [p] for r in result for p in pool]
    return result
```

Which we can then use to achieve the same goal:

```py
values = [['A', 'B'], [1, 2]]
values_perms = product(list(permutations(l)) for l in values)
```

But this will be slower, prone to bugs and it means more code to maintain. The only interesting thing here I think is to implement it yourself and see what you end up with, then simply use `itertools`.